# I can't get this to work, methods & instance variables

Tags: java, variables, methods, instance

I'm new to programming, I'm sorry if this is a silly mistake, but I keep getting this error `"CompanyAddress.java:11: error: cannot find symbol System.out.println(testObject.getName(CompanyName));"` I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

The main.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CompanyAddress
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     test testObject = new test();
     System.out.println("Enter name: ");
     String input = scan.nextLine();
     testObject.getName(input);
     System.out.println(testObject.getName(CompanyName));
  }
}
```

my test.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test 
{
    String Name;

    public String getName(String CompanyName) 
    {
        Name = CompanyName;
        return Name;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First of all** you need to declare your variable `companyName`, before passing it to your method.

**Secondly,** your method: -

```
public String getName(String CompanyName) 
{
    Name = CompanyName;
    return Name;
}
```

Seems strange to me. You are using the same method as `getter and setter`.

You should have `separate setter and getter`: -

```
public void setName(String companyName) {
    name = companyName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

And invoke them separately.

```
testObject.setName(companyName);

System.out.println(testObject.getName());
```

**Just a suggestion: -**

Follow Java Naming Convention. Field names and method names should start with lowercase alphabet.

Comment: @Downvoter.. Please comment, because I don't think what is your intent behind downvoting.

Comment: I upvoted, because this is the best answer so far. In addition to answering the OP's question you also added som good advice, which from the OP's code examples, was needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it, but is there anyway of only using one method?

Comment: Yeah, you could change your getName method so that it checked if the input parameter was null, and if so only returned the existing value - and then you would just use `System.out.println(testObject.getName(null));`. But that really would be a terrible method to have in your application.

Comment: @Kingboom4.. Why would you want to use a single method. Well, it's not impossible, but trust me, that would absolutely be very bad design. This the basic structure of a class, having `constructor`, `fields`, and `setters` and `getters` for them. And you should no doubt follow it.

Comment: @ Rohit Yh I did follow it, I was just curious of whether that would be possible. Thank you very much everyone!

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the variable `CompanyName`. Something  like this:

```
String CompanyName = "CompanyName1";
System.out.println(testObject.getName(CompanyName));
```

Since you are modifying a variable you should do:

```
public class test
{
       String Name;

        public void setName(String CompanyName) {this.Name = CompanyName;}

        public String getName()                 {return Name;}
```

}

The method `getName` will return the name of the "Company" and the `setName` will modify the name of the "Company". This way you can **separate different concerns**.

Furthermore, you can in the future call the method getName without modifying the actual name of the company.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(testObject.getName(CompanyName));
```

What `CompanyName` this here? It is not known symbol. It could be `System.out.println(testObject.getName("CompanyName"));`

or

```
String CompanyName ="name";
System.out.println(testObject.getName(CompanyName);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you wamt your program to do something like below. A function `setName()` that will set the passed value to name and one `getName()` which will return the value of name.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test 
{
    String Name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public String setName(String companyName)
    {
        this.Name=companyName;
    }
}
```

Now

```
public class CompanyAddress
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     test testObject = new test();
     System.out.println("Enter name: ");
     String input = scan.nextLine();
     testObject.setName(input);
     System.out.println(testObject.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone ,if you think better formatting/ spellings need to be checked. Feel free to edit. M on a phone. Cand do much About formatting. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rename your "getName to "setName" (because it is a setter) and add a proper getter to your class and use that:

```
public class test 
{
    String Name;

    public void setName(String CompanyName) 
    {
        Name = CompanyName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

then:

```
 System.out.println(testObject.getName());
```

Also, it will help you if you adhere to standard naming conventions:

- Class names start with a capital letter
- Method, variable and parameter names start with a lowercase letter